# PHP 5.3 and multithreading

Tags: php, multithreading

Does php 5.3 support multinthreading ? Because I was trying to create a class that extends from Thread but it doesn't know it !

```
class My extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        /** ... **/
    }
}
$my = new My();
var_dump($my->start());
```

This script shows me this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php

Comment: @Mattia I'm sorry I don't get your point.

Comment: You need to install the extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install pthreads extension as said in [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php)
By the way you can install [pthreads](https://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads) using [pecl](https://pecl.php.net/)
I think (but not sure) that you can use pthreads-2.0.10.
So :

```
pecl install phthreads-2.0.10
```

Then you can extends Thread class.
Please read the documentation before asking something like that.

Comment: Thnx, but I wanted to know if it's included in php 5.3 because the server, where I'm hosting my web application I don't have access to install this extension in it, so is there any other possibility to do it ?

Comment: No, you have to install the extension to use it.